# Angularjs Factory value doesn't update in multiple views

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple `factory` to get products list from data base and also to toggle if the product is favorite or not (based on user interaction).

```
function factoryProduct($http,$filter) {
    var data = {};
        data.list = [];

    var service = {
        getData:    _getData,
        toggleFav:  _toggleFav
    };
    return service;

    function _getData() {
        return $http.get('my/url/get.php').then(function(res){
            data.list = res;
            return res;
        });
    };
    function _toggleFav(value) {
        /* data manipulation here... */
        return $http.post('my/url/post.php', data).then(function(res){
            if (res==1) {
                return $filter('filter')(data.list)[index].inFav = value;
            };
        };
    };
}
```

This is used in multiple views, such as home, category page, favorite list, wishlist, etc.. And thus it's used inside multiple controllers, where I inject the factory and then pass the data to the view.

The toggle function, since it's the same, it's called from within a directive, but is also simple, like this:

```
scope.toggleFav = function(data, index) {
    /*data verification here*/
    factoryProduct.toggleFav(value);
}
```

And in the controller, like this:

```
function MainCtrl(factoryProduct) {
    var vm = this;
    factoryProduct.getData().then(function(res){
        vm.list = res;
    })
}
function CategoryCtrl(factoryProduct) {
    var vm = this;
    /* category taken from url parameter */
    factoryProduct.getData().then(function(res){
        $filter('filter')(res, {category: urlParam});
        vm.list = res;
    })
}
```

I can get data properly, make the filter and show the correct product list on each view. I also can toggle the favorite and both, the filter and the database, are properly updated.

#### The problem

The problem starts when I need to change view. For example:

If I'm on the home page, set a product as favorite, go to the contact page and then comeback to the home page, the product I just set as favorite is now as 'non-favorite' item, even if it's favorite in the database and also was updated before going to the contact page.

I'm using this:

```
var data = {};
    data.list = [];
```

Because I saw many answers saying to have a static array and only manipulate the data inside this array. But it's not working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's not working because you are bypassing it when you get your data from server and not storing the response within the factory

Comment: In your factory, you are missing the second argument, `index` in the `_toggleFav` function.

Comment: @charlietfl I missed it when passing to the question, but it's set, I'll update the question.

Comment: @georgeawg the arguments are passed correct, but I do some verifications before actually updating the data. To check if it's already favorite or not.

Comment: Are you certain your views are being loaded each time you navigate away and come back?  For example, if you have them in a tab controller, the views might only load when the whole tab controller loads.  Also, are you sure you aren't navigating away and coming back before the 'favorite' update has time to propagate to the backend?

Comment: @dustmouse yes, they load, because I used console.log to check this, and it's returning the data each time a new view is loaded. Also it does update on database before everything else because the visual change only happens if the response is positive. I think it has something to do with the $filter, I think it only updates the object itself, and not the whole list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to set  up storing data in factory for the duration of the life of the page.

Using a `resolve` in router can be very helpful to populate data stores. Then when controllers fire the data already exists.

Another one is to check if data exists and if it does return a `$q.resolve(data)`.
If it doesn't exist you return the `$http` promise that first stores the data and then returns the stored object reference.

Another I just picked up on recently that is helpful if numerous parts of app may ask for same data before a single request has completed.

You can store the original promise made. You can use `then()` on that promise any time you want within the app lifecycle

```
app.factory('Factory', function($http){

  var dataPromise=null,  data=null;

  function getData() {
    if (!dataPromise) {
      console.warn('NEW REQUEST BEING MADE')
      dataPromise = $http.get('data.json').then(function(resp) {
        // store the data
        data = resp.data
        // return data stored in factory
        return data;
      })
    }else{
      console.info('Existing promise being returned')
    }
    return dataPromise;
  }

  return {
    getData: getData
  }   

});
```

This last approach will prevent 2 parts of the app making 2 simultaneous requests if the first one hasn't completed

A final approach that is used by `$resource` is to return an empty object that is stored in factory. Then when requests are completed they merge data into that object without breaking the original object reference. Then when that object is passed directly through to views angular watchers will catch changes and do updates

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fV4FFcfC4CR7gDjrW69h?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: But this is basically what I'm doing. The only difference is I'm not checking for an existing data, but the problem ins't with the main data itself, but when I update a value from an object in the list. Isn't this the case?

Comment: This answered the question of how to store the data locally while app is loaded. As for why you aren't seeing proper data from server after updates there isn't anything shown that would help us understand that problem

Comment: note that if you want to use `$filter` you need return the filter to a variable. You are bypassing the filter and referencing the full list ...`vm.list=$filter(...`

Comment: How should I do this? Because the problem is with the toggle of the favorite.

Comment: is the idea to filter the same data as in `_getData()` ? Or is tht post making request for different data? Not enough known about relationships

Comment: yes. I'll get the list of products in the getData. Then the toggleFav() will update an especific product from that list and set the value of `inFav: false` to `inFav: true`. I'm able to this already, but when I change the view, this value return to the original value taken from the getData();

Comment: well `scope.toggleFav` doesn't seem to change any properties on existing objects so it appears you are sending unedited data to server

Comment: It calls the function within the factory, then I make the data verification and apply a value of true or false.

Comment: well we can't see any of that. So this question is 2 parts...how to store data locally...and how to find a bug. But we can't see the code for the bug. Suggest you start a new question with only the relevant favorites code, including the html that triggers it

Comment: But it's there. Is the _toggleFav() inside the factory. This function is called from a directive via the scope.toggleFav = function.. And then I change the value with an http.post and on the view with the $filter

Comment: create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: I was trying to apply your solution, but I got stuck on the beggining. If there is no data set yet, I can get it in the controller just fine. But if there is data, I get this error: `.then(...) is not a function`. I know it's because of the promise, but if the data already existis, how can I pass it to controller?